# form action not redirected to the route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this controller:

```
  public function category($name)
  {
        $ch = DB::select('select * from quiz where category=?',['$name']);
        return View('quiz.index',['quiz'=>$ch]);     

 }
```

returning to the view `quiz.index`. this view has a form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('quiz/check/$quiz->category')}}"
{!! csrf_field() !!} 

@foreach ($quiz as $q)

@if($q->level=='1')
{{ $q->qid }}.  
{{ $q->question }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='1'>     
{{ $q->opt1 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='2'>     
{{ $q->opt2 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='3'>    
{{ $q->opt3 }}<br>
<input type='radio' name='mycheck[{{$q->qid}}]' value='4'>   
{{ $q->opt4 }}<br><br>
@endif
@endforeach        
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Get result</button>
                            </form>
```

what is wrong with the action in the form. it is not redirected to this route: in other words `$quiz->category` in action might not be working.

```
Route::post('/quiz/check/{name}', 'playquiz@check');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
{{url("quiz/check/{$quiz[0]->category}")}
```

or in your controller change to:

```
return View('quiz.index')->with('show');
```

and the View:

```
{{url("quiz/check/$show->category")}
```

Comment: tried this, the form is redirected to `/quiz/check/$quiz[0]->category`

Comment: if you try the second option, modyfing the controller and view? @Steve

Comment: in this case you access to attributes with `{{$show->qid}}` @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable and a method call inside single quotes. Either append it or use double quotes with curly brackets. In other words, don't do this:

```
url('quiz/check/$quiz->category')
```

but do either of these:

```
url('quiz/check/'.$quiz->category)
url("quiz/check/{$quiz->category}")
```

Comment: with both methods, i am getting 'Trying to get property of non-object' error in index.blade.php

Comment: @Steve This is because `$quiz` is an array. Try accessing the first element: `$quiz[0]->category`

Comment: @TimoSta tried that but the form redirects to `/quiz/check/$quiz[0]->category`

Comment: @Steve did you follow Joel Hinz' suggestions?

Comment: @TimoSta yes.  'Trying to get property of non-object' error is what i got.

Comment: Well, my addition to Joel's answer together with his answer should solve your problem. Both address to distinct issues.